# Узнать размера файла по условию

Tags: c#, циклы, коллекции

Нужно в цикле определять размер файла, и если он меньше чем в условии то удалять его путь из коллекции

```
 string[] pathlog =
            {
                "\\Folders\\text.txt",
                "\\Folders\\text.txt",
                "\\Folders\\text.txt"

            };
  List<string> passion = new List<string>(pathlog);

for (int i = passion.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)             
                    if (passion[i].Length <= 20480 * 1024)
                    passion.RemoveAt(i);
```

При умножении список файлов не выводится, при делении выводятся все файлы, что я делаю не верно?

Comment: Размер чего, по-вашему, выдает ``passion[i].Length``? И в каких единицах.

Comment: @Эникейщик,  passion[i] содержит пути до файлов, по идеи размер файла должен, но как понимаю возможно длину пути выдает?

Comment: По какой идее там должен быть размер файла? Почему вы думаете, что компилятор вообще знает, что это путь к файлу? ``passion[i]`` содержит строку. И выдается количество ``char`` в этой строке. Если написать в строку "километр", вы же не будете ожидать 1000, потому что в километре 1000 метров.

Comment: @Эникейщик, вопрос состоял, в том, что я делаю не правильно, ближе к сути вопроса пожалуйста

Comment: Не считаете длину файлов. Да и вообще о файлах в коде ничего нет.

Comment: @Эникейщик, есть коллекция с путями до файлов `passion`, в цикле, получается, считаю длину пути, но как в цикле определить по этим путям размер файла? Пример кода можно?

Comment: @Bortman смотри класс FileInfo. Для каждого пути создавайте экземпляр класса FileInfo и в условии проверяй свойство этого класса Length.

Comment: @Эникейщик, FileInfo я с самого начала смотрел, его в цикл не вставишь,сам List напрямую в FileInfo тоже не вставишь, нужно в цикле как то проверить размер файла, файлов будет неопределенное количество постоянно, размер коллекции будет меняться в процессе.

Comment: Может быть человеку нужно перечитать азы программирования по C#?

Comment: @ГеннадийП, тут в основном и переписывают советы по азам без примеров и фактов,  а рабочий код, даже не с данными из вопроса, привести никто не может в основном.

Comment: @Bortman вам следует показывать всё, что вы пробовали. Если вы уже пробовали `FileInfo` - покажите это в вопросе, и вам скажут, где вы ошиблись. `FileInfo` легко вставляется в цикл, никаких проблем. По сути, всё что есть в моем ответе вам уже тут советовали, я только свел это все к какому то виду.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
var pathlog = new string[]
    {
        "\\Folders\\text.txt",
        "\\Folders\\text.txt",
        "\\Folders\\text.txt"
    };

var passion = pathlog
    .Where(x => File.Exists(x)) // выбираем только те файлы, что есть на диске
    .Where(x => new FileInfo(x).Length > 20480 * 1024) // фильтруем файлы по размеру
    .ToList();
```

Как сделать в цикле

```
List<string> passion = new List<string>(); // пустой!

for (int i = 0; i < pathlog.Length; i++)
{
    if (!File.Exists(pathlog[i])) continue;

    var info = new FileInfo(pathlog[i])
    if (info.Length > 20480 * 1024)
        passion.Add(pathlog[i]); // добавляем по условию в список 
}
```

Comment: спасибо запишу, но интересно, как в цикле это все сделать, чтобы записать в List и оттуда брать данные?

Comment: @Bortman добавил апдейт в ответ

Comment: @Bortman поправил условия. Вы же хотите большие файлы добавить в результат, верно? В любом случае, это просто пример, правьте условия как вам надо.

Comment: переписал Ваш пример под свой код, все стабильно работает. Спасибо, ни в первый раз помогаете мне!)

Comment: @Bortman пожалуйста